# Schedule reboot servers

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

What I have does work but I'm fairly certain there is an easier way to do this, or at the very least a better way.

```
  $servers = "knesdcsf01" , "knesdcsf02" , "knemdcsf01" , "knemdcsf02"
  foreach ($server in $servers)
  {
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 60
  Restart-Computer -computer $server
  }
```

What I would like to have happen is for the servers in the list to get rebooted one at a time. This what i came up with but instead of using a sleep cmd what would be another way?

Comment: I dont want all servers to go down at once.

Comment: I suppose you could use -Wait so that it wont restart the next one until the current one has restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Wait Command to wait, till the computer is restarted.

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName "ComputerToRestart" -Wait
```

You can also, add an optional timeout in seconds.. till when the script will wait for the computer to restart

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName "ComputerToRestart" -Wait -Timeout 180
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for different ways of doing the same thing.